# How can I pass objects/values trough multiple pipes?

Tags: powershell, pipeline

`Get-Mailbox username` gets me for instance the "Displayname" of a user.
`Get-MailboxRegionalConfiguration` gets me some more information.

I want to use

```
PS> Get-Mailbox username | Get-MailboxRegionalConfiguration

Identity             Language        DateFormat TimeFormat TimeZone
--------             --------        ---------- ---------- --------
                     en-US           M/d/yyyy   h:mm tt    W. Europe Standard Time
```

and I need also the `Displayname` from the `Get-Mailbox`. Can I do this with pipes?

So far I have to use foreach and want to avoid that:

```
$MBs = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited 

foreach ($MB in $MBs) { 
    $Name = $MB.DisplayName 
    $MRC = $MB | Get-MailboxRegionalConfiguration 
    $Lang = $MRC.Language 
    $DF = $MRC.DateFormat 
    $TF = $MRC.TimeFormat 
    $TZ = $MRC.TimeZone
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to extend the objects from `Get-MailboxRegionalConfiguration` with additional information:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_.DisplayName
    $_ | Get-MailboxRegionalConfiguration |
        Select-Object *,@{n='DisplayName',e={$name}}
}
```

Comment: my understanding is that `Select-Object` used in that manner does not "extend" an object like `Add-Member` does. instead, it creates a NEW object with the listed props. which is correct?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I didn't mean "extend" in the strictest sense of the word. `Select-Object` obviously creates a new object (since the type changes to `PSCustomObject`).

Comment: yes, but is that obvious to someone who is new to this? i have dealt with folks who were not at all clear on the various ways `Select-Object` works ... sometimes passing on the original, sometimes making a new object - all depending on just what parameters you use.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey They're probably unaware of it. But the more important question is: does it make a difference for them? In most cases I'd argue the answer to the latter question is "no".

Comment: i see your point ... but i am not sure that i agree OR disagree with it. [*blush*] that means you are likely quite correct. [*grin*]